# Custom post fields

Tags: theme-development, custom-field

I am new with WordPress development and working on a Recipes website and i am using custom fields for my recipes posts. I am creating these custom fields with ACF plugin.
But my client wants to create these input fields with single click on post edit page for each of the post separately because he want to add steps for recipe and these steps will be different for each of the post. 
So he wants to create these fields on his own and can create any number of these fields like in this link.

http://jsfiddle.net/nj4N4/7/

Is there any plugin that can help me to create similar functionality for each recipe posts? Your help and guidance will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the repeater field of ACF.

Comment: Ok Thnak you for your suggestion. I will try to use this now.

Comment: Ok, If it is the right answer for your question, then don't forget to mark it as accepted. Thank You.

Comment: Yes i accept this answer and thank you for your help. I had to purchase pro version of ACF plugin because repeater fields are not available in free version.

Comment: Yes ACF Repeater fields are only avilable in pro version. But I think the price of ACF pro version isn't so high as you get lots of support from it. ACF pro version will help you to do everything with wordpress...Have a nice coding...